# Get incremented value silverlight RIA WCF?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

My Silverlight application inserts records tp a table named **Prscrpts**. The **prescriptionno** is the primary key.

I also maintain another table named **PrscrptRange** which has the lastest prescription number. there are 3 records in this table, depending on the type of the prescription. eg: Medication :3035 , Plain : 74023, External :503336. I use three different ranges depending on the type of prescription.

Now, what I need is whenever I insert a record into the prescrpts table, I need to check whether the prescription is of type medication, if its medication, get the corresponding value from the **PrscrptRange**  table and increment it and use this new value as the prescriptionno and update the **PrscrptRange** table and insert the new prescription record.

How can I do this in the client side? What I need to take care of is that no two person should use the same **prescriptionno.** (concurrency) This is an online order entry system.

Please Please Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this on the client, you can do the following:

1. Before you save get and increment the prescription number, within a transaction
2. When you save send the prescription number with the request

The problem with this that if the client decides not to save, you get holes in the series.

I would have moved this functionality to the server, increment the prescription number and save the prescription in the same transaction.